# How to unpivot a pandas dataframe based on some grouped column?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to unpivot this below dataframe.

**My dataframe:**

[image]

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for [`pd.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html):

```
df.melt(id_vars=['id', 'col1', 'col2'])

   id col1 col2 variable  value
0   1    a    e     val1      3
1   1    a    e     val2      7
```